# How do I reach the smoke beacon in TR:DE?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I'm playing *Tomb Raider: Definitive Edition* on XB1. I just had the conversation with Beard Face Guy (real name unknown) about making sacrifices, and I'm supposed to reach a smoke beacon to find the crashed copilot. **How do I get to the beacon from this waterfall canyon area?** This is where I am:

[image: map location]

I see there is a zipline very high up leading from the cliffs towards the smoke beacon objective. I've made my way up as high as I can on the right side of the canyon (if you're looking at the waterfall) but I don't know how to cross, or climb down and scale the other side (also note, the craggy wall in front of me, across the canyon, doesn't highlight in survival view as being climbable).

[image: Waterfall view]

If I jump down, I can scale the roof that you see to the left of Lara, where the empty bird nest is, but that's about as high as I can get on that side of the canyon. The zipline I need to get to (I think) is a little higher and further to left, a little hard to see in the pic. Am I headed in the right direction here?

Comment: This should be tagged `tomb-raider-2013` instead of `tomb-raider`.  This puzzle should be solved the same way on every platform, so the `xbox-one` tag isn't necessary, either.

Comment: As it turns out, dying is an option. The respawn put me directly in front of the beacon. Still not sure how to get there on my own though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you facing the same way in the map picture as in the other one? Because on the map you are facing away from the objective and are quite far away from it. You don't need to get to an especially high place to get to the smoke beacon.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0AoZ5w9aE0U) is a video where the player gets to the beacon, but it is not a guide and a lot of time is spent doing other stuff, so here is a quick explanation.

To reach the beacon you need to advance through the mountain village by using rope arrows to climb from hill to hill. Try going further east from where you are until the smoke beacon is in sight.

Head to the tomb here, by following the path using rope arrows:

[image: Tomb Raider 4]

Your goal is a hill that is close to the beacon and at the same hight. It has a little wodden temple structure on it with a document lying around. There is only this one way to get to the beacon by using a rope arrow to make a zipline right in front of it.

[image: Tomb Raider 3]

[image: Tomb Raider 4]

[image: Tomb Raider 2]

I took all pictures from the video, so the quality is not that great.

Comment: I was indeed facing a different direction in the map view, I think I readjusted for the second shot. I just went back though and I see the spots you are talking about now too, and thanks for the screenshots and video, they helped a lot.